# Is there a secret star in the castle courtyard?

Tags: super-mario-64

In the back yard of the castle, there's the course called "Big Boos Haunt", but there's also this curious sign in the corner that says something about a triple jump and a wall kick. The thing is that right near that is a convenient wall, which might be doable with the aforementioned combination.

[image]

Is there a secret star here, or anything useful?

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly post a broader shot?  My memory is a little fuzzy here.

Comment: Sure, hang on. (15 char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually based on [this](http://www.sca.ch/mario/mariosc.htm) (beware, spoilers) I'm going to go ahead and say no.  Now that I think about it I remember being similarly confused by the sign but could not find a star nearby, and that site confirms that the secret stars are elsewhere.

**Edit:** With the second screenshot I remember even more.  There's definitely nothing there :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that site, but thanks for the spoilers warning.